# Is there any problem while returning the "char pointer" from function

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, scope, c-strings

The code below is expected to return a string containing only numbers from an user entered string.

Also the returned string should group the numbers in three digits and put a '-' between them.

Everything runs fine, code compiles without any error, but the `char*` is not being returned from function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char* phoneNo(char*); 

void main(){

    char str[100];
    char *strpass = str;

    printf("Enter the string: ");
    fgets(str,100,stdin);

    printf("Entered stringis: %s\n",str);

    char *result = phoneNo(strpass);
    printf("Returned char* is: %s\n",result);
}

char* phoneNo(char *strpass){

    char str[100];
    strcpy(str,strpass);
    printf("Char[] in Function: %s",str);

    char answer[100];
    char * result;
    result = ( char* ) malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    result=answer;
    //printf("Char* pointed to Char[]: %s\n",result);

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=3;

    while(str[i]!='\0'){

        if(str[i]=='1'||str[i]=='2'||str[i]=='3'||str[i]=='4'||str[i]=='5'||str[i]=='6'||str[i]=='7'||str[i]=='8'||str[i]=='9'||str[i]=='0')
        {


            if(j==0){

                answer[j]=str[i];
                answer[j+1]='\0';
                j++;
                i++;
                continue;
            }

            if(j==k){
                answer[j]='-';
                answer[j+1]='\0';
                j++;
                k+=4;
            }else{
                answer[j]=str[i];
                answer[j+1]='\0';
                j++;
                i++;
            }
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    printf("Char* to be returned: %s\n",result);

    return (char *)result;
}
```

Comment: "the char* is not being returned from function." You make this conclusion based on what evidence?

Comment: What do you think `result=answer;` does in `phoneNo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet

```
char answer[100];
char * result;
result = ( char* ) malloc(100*sizeof(char));
result=answer;
```

has a memory leak because the address of the allocated memory is lost due to this statement

```
result=answer;
```

Now the pointer `result` points to the local array `answer` and returned from the function that results in undefined behavior because the array will not be alive after exiting the function.

Use the allocated dynamically array for processing instead of the local array `answer`.

Pay attention to that instead of this compound if statement

```
if(str[i]=='1'||str[i]=='2'||str[i]=='3'||str[i]=='4'||str[i]=='5'||str[i]=='6'||str[i]=='7'||str[i]=='8'||str[i]=='9'||str[i]=='0')
```

it is much better to write

```
if ( isdigit( ( unsigned char )str[i] ) )
```

And the function shall be declared like

```
char* phoneNo(const char *strpass);
```

that is its parameter must have the qualifier `const`.

I would write the function the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * phoneNo( const char *s )
{
    const size_t GROUP_SIZE = 3;

    size_t digits_count = 0;

    for ( const char *p = s; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( isdigit( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++digits_count;
    }

    char *result = malloc( digits_count + digits_count / GROUP_SIZE + sizeof( ( char )'\0' ) );

    size_t i = 0;

    for ( size_t k = 0; *s; ++s )
    {
        if ( isdigit( ( unsigned char )*s ) )
        {
            if ( k == GROUP_SIZE )
            {
                if ( i != 0 )
                {
                    result[i++] = '-';
                }
                k = 0;
            }

            result[i++] = *s;
            ++k;
        }
    }

    result[i] = '\0';

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "123456789";

    char *result = phoneNo( s );

    puts( result );

    free( result );

    s = "12\t34567\t89";

    result = phoneNo( s );

    puts( result );

    free( result );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
123-456-789
123-456-789
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you clarify , 'Use the allocated dynamically array for processing instead of the local array answer.' or else post the corrected code

Comment: @vikasdamdhare Just remove the declarations of str and answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you allocate memory for `result`, then in the next line `result=answer;` you immediately have it point elsewhere, creating a memory leak while instead pointing at a local variable. This is the bug.